# Display additional Column in the SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, fusion, oracle-apps

I have a SQL select query which returns the Customer Contact Email Address information to send the Customer Statements given below

```html
    SELECT hp.party_name
      ,hzl.location_id "Bill To Number"
      ,hzps.party_site_name "Customer Bill To Name"
      ,hcp.email_address "Customer Email Address"
FROM 
    hz_parties hp,
    hz_cust_accounts hca, 
    hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcsa, 
    hz_cust_site_uses_all hcsu,
    hz_party_sites hzps ,
    hz_locations hzl,
    hz_cust_account_roles hcar,
    hz_contact_points hcp, 
    hz_relationships hr     
WHERE 1=1
and hp.party_id             = hca.party_id
and hca.cust_account_id     = hcsa.cust_account_id
and hcsa.cust_acct_site_id  = hcsu.cust_acct_site_id  
and hcsa.party_site_id      = hzps.party_site_id(+)
and hzps.location_id        = hzl.location_id(+)
and hcsu.site_use_code      = 'BILL_TO'
and NVL(hcar.status,'A')    ='A'
and hcar.cust_account_id    = hca.cust_account_id
and hcar.cust_acct_site_id  = hcsa.cust_acct_site_id
and hcar.relationship_id    = hcp.relationship_id
and hcp.contact_point_type  = 'EMAIL'
and nvl(hcp.end_date,SYSDATE+5) > SYSDATE
and hcp.relationship_id     = hr.relationship_id 
and hr.relationship_code    = 'CONTACT_OF' 
and hr.object_id            = hp.party_id;
```

Result of the above query is

```css
PARTY_NAME  Bill_To_Number  Customer_Bill_To_Name   Customer_Email_Address
Party 1         1006746009  CUSTOM PRODUCTS         newton@testemail.net
Party 1         1006746009  CUSTOM PRODUCTS         lorne@testemail.net
Party 2         1006746010  PAINT COMPANY           tgliwell@testemail.com
Party 2         1006746010  PAINT COMPANY           APAL@testemail.com
Party 3         1006746011  ADVANCED MATERIALS  invo@testemail.com
Party 4         1006746012  ADVANCED PRODUCTS   accpayable@testemail.com
```

I need to modify the query to display one more additional column using in the select statement(i.e., Dummy) with values either 'A' or 'B'. Logic to derive the value is, if a Customer having multiple emails for the first record it should be 'A' and for the second record it should be 'B'.
In the above output Party1 and Party2 are having multiple email ids so Dummy column should have A for first record and B for second record as given below

```html
    PARTY_NAME  Bill_To_Number  Customer_Bill_To_Name   Customer_Email_Address   Dummy
Party 1         1006746009  CUSTOM PRODUCTS         newton@testemail.net     A
Party 1         1006746009  CUSTOM PRODUCTS         lorne@testemail.net      B
Party 2         1006746010  PAINT COMPANY           tgliwell@testemail.com   A
Party 2         1006746010  PAINT COMPANY           APAL@testemail.com       B
Party 3         1006746011  ADVANCED MATERIALS  invo@testemail.com       A
Party 4         1006746012  ADVANCED PRODUCTS   accpayable@testemail.com A
```

Note: party_name column is the Primary key column.

Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: how you determine which is a or b datatables have nor inherit order

Comment: Your query doesn't include any `order by`, so what determines "first" vs "second" record? If you're trying to determine primary/secondary e-mail, this should probably be a property of the contact record.

Comment: there is no particular condition to determine which record should have A and which record should have B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number the rows for each `party_name`/`location_id`/`party_site_name` combination and then convert that number to a character:

```sql
SELECT hp.party_name
      ,hzl.location_id "Bill To Number"
      ,hzps.party_site_name "Customer Bill To Name"
      ,hcp.email_address "Customer Email Address"
      ,CHR(
         64
         + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY hp.party_name, hzl.location_id, hzps.party_site_name
             ORDER BY hcp.email_address
           )
       ) AS Dummy
FROM   hz_parties hp
       INNER JOIN hz_cust_accounts hca
       ON hp.party_id             = hca.party_id
       INNER JOIN hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcsa
       ON hca.cust_account_id     = hcsa.cust_account_id
       INNER JOIN hz_cust_site_uses_all hcsu
       ON hcsa.cust_acct_site_id  = hcsu.cust_acct_site_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_party_sites hzps
       ON hcsa.party_site_id      = hzps.party_site_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_locations hzl
       ON hzps.location_id        = hzl.location_id
       INNER JOIN hz_relationships hr
       ON hr.object_id            = hp.party_id
       INNER JOIN hz_contact_points hcp
       ON hcp.relationship_id     = hr.relationship_id
       INNER JOIN hz_cust_account_roles hcar
       ON  hcar.cust_account_id    = hca.cust_account_id
       and hcar.cust_acct_site_id  = hcsa.cust_acct_site_id
       and hcar.relationship_id    = hcp.relationship_id
WHERE  hcsu.site_use_code      = 'BILL_TO'
and    (hcar.status = 'A' OR hcar.status IS NULL)
and    hcp.contact_point_type  = 'EMAIL'
and    (hcp.end_date > SYSDATE OR hcp.end_date IS NULL)
and    hr.relationship_code    = 'CONTACT_OF';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cs7WdCLP)

Comment: I have just used the derivation part from your query in the query I have posted. It is working as expected. Thanks

Comment: @Anji007 Move the `INNER JOIN` for `hcp` before the join for `hcar`.

Comment: Yes, that is worked. Many thanks for your help.